# Can an aura buff an aura?

Tags: smite

Specifically, I want to know if the aura buff from my [Rod of Asclepius](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Rod_of_Asclepius) that increases ally healing and restoration also affects the HP5 they get from my [Sovereignty](http://smite.gamepedia.com/Sovereignty).

Granted, the buff would be minute, but I'm still curious.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since it buffs the global hp regeneration per 5 seconds, it also includes the items that buff HP5.

The flat hp5 of all items will apply (including sovereignty) and then the Asclepius rod will take effect.

So yes, it is a minor heal upgrade but a heal upgrade nontheless, got to keep in mind that rod of asclepius is more used for healing spells and not regular regeneration though !